# How to optimally interleave K arrays of same fixed N length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, list, optimization

I have the following data structure which is a list of lists.

Input Data:

```
const attributes = {
AO:(15174) [Number …]
jointId:(15174) [Number …]
paletteIdx:(15174) [Number …]
position:(15174) [Array(3) …]
normal:(15174) [Array(3) …]
....//additional variable amount of properties
}
```

expected output:

```
[AO[0], jointId[0], PaletteIdx[0], position[0][0], 
position[0][1], position[0][2], normal[0][0], 
normal[0][1], normal[0][2], AO[1], jointId[1], ...]
```

I need to interleave the lists into one combined flat array. I have tried a few different solutions (nested loops) that didn't seem to scale. My latest attempt is using `eval` for some code generation to coerce a nested loop solution into one pass.

```
const attributeNames = Object.keys(attributes);

const funcBody = attributeNames.map((attributeName) => {
  return `attributes.${attributeName}[index],`;
}).join('\n');


const output = eval(`
  attributes[attributeNames[0]].reduce((acc, value, index) => {
    acc = acc.concat(${funcBody});
    return acc;
  }, []);
`);
```

This is a non frequent operation that I can maybe move to an offline process, unfortunately, that would be a large refactor of an existing system.

Comment: Could you please add an examle of input data and desired output?

Comment: Code generation might help to speed it up indeed, but `concat`? Come on, you can do better than that.

Comment: Can you please post the simple nested loop solution? The `eval` code is really hard to understand, I don't get what exactly the data format is and which result you need.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you'd like it to "scale?"

Comment: @Bergi please offer a helpful suggestion instead of internet comment data pollution. What do you recommend as an alternative to concat?

Comment: @kevzettler `concat` needs to create a complete new array, copying all existing elements (I had assumed that you knew this when you are going for advanced methods like code generation). If you aim for speed, you should append to one existing array only (using `push` or direct assignment).

Comment: Why is the order of `position` `[0][0..2]`, but `normal` is `[0][3], [1][0], [1][2]` in the example?

Answer (score 1):

(By the way, to avoid browser interruptions, one can also utilize a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).)

Just going with your example, which did not include in the output an element I inserted to make one array longer than the other three, what I saw in the output was tantamount to a column by column traversal of the lists that also assumes they are of equal length.

We can easily code that with a `for` loop. Please include more specific details about what your needs are if this would not meet them. For elements that are arrays, we can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const attributes = {
  AO:[1,2,3],
  jointId:[4,5,6],
  paletteIdx:[[7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15]],
  position:[[16,17,18], [19,20,21], [22,23,24]]
}

const attributeNames = Object.keys(attributes);

const funcBody = attributeNames.map((attributeName) => {
  return `attributes.${attributeName}[index],`;
}).join('\n');


const output = eval(`
  attributes[attributeNames[0]].reduce((acc, value, index) => {
    acc = acc.concat(${funcBody});
    return acc;
  }, []);
`);

console.log('\'output\' from code in the question: ' + JSON.stringify(output));

var output1 = [];

var n = attributes[ Object.keys(attributes)[0] ].length;

for (let col=0; col<n; col++){
  for (let row in attributes){
    if (Array.isArray(attributes[row][col]))
      output1.push(...attributes[row][col])
    else
      output1.push(attributes[row][col]);
  }
}

console.log('\'output1\' from column traversal: ' + JSON.stringify(output1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you needed nested loops. It appears to be quite straightforward:

```
const { AO: {length}, AO, jointId, paletteIdx, position, normal } = attributes;
const output = []; // test whether using `new Array(length * 9);` is better
for (let i=0, j=0; i<length; i++) {
  output[j++] = AO[i];
  output[j++] = jointId[i];
  output[j++] = PaletteIdx[i];
  output[j++] = position[i][0];
  output[j++] = position[i][1];
  output[j++] = position[i][2];
  output[j++] = normal[i][0];
  output[j++] = normal[i][1];
  output[j++] = normal[i][2];
}
```

I can't imagine anything being faster. Since you are not using previously-unknown properties in the code, I don't think dynamic code generation would be of any help here.

Comment: I am using unknown properties in the code that is why I am using code generation...

Comment: @kevzettler Oh ok, but still you should then generate something like my code not the inefficient thing with `reduce` and `concat` :-)